# cabal: how to automatically update the build-depends field in the .cabal file?

Tags: haskell, cabal

Is there a way to automatically update the *build-depends* field in the *.cabal-file*? For example, if we start with the following `.cabal` file:

```
name:           HUnit
version:        1.1.1
synopsis:       A unit testing framework for Haskell
homepage:       http://hunit.sourceforge.net/
category:       Testing
author:         Dean Herington
license:        BSD3
license-file:   LICENSE
cabal-version:  >= 1.10
build-type:     Simple

library
  build-depends:      base >= 2 && < 4
  exposed-modules:    Test.HUnit.Base, Test.HUnit.Lang,
                      Test.HUnit.Terminal, Test.HUnit.Text, Test.HUnit
  default-extensions: CPP
```

Then, install a package:

```
cabal install warp
```

Now, I have to add `warp >=3.0 && <3.1` to the `build-depends` field, to make the file look like this:

```
name:           HUnit
version:        1.1.1
synopsis:       A unit testing framework for Haskell
homepage:       http://hunit.sourceforge.net/
category:       Testing
author:         Dean Herington
license:        BSD3
license-file:   LICENSE
cabal-version:  >= 1.10
build-type:     Simple

library
  build-depends:      base >= 2 && < 4, warp >=3.0 && <3.1
  exposed-modules:    Test.HUnit.Base, Test.HUnit.Lang,
                      Test.HUnit.Terminal, Test.HUnit.Text, Test.HUnit
  default-extensions: CPP
```

My question is: how do we update this file automatically?

Comment: emacs haskell-mode does that for me, but I don't know of a general solution.

Comment: @ReinHenrichs I think that the code for the feature you mentioned is this  [haskell-mode at github, search for defun haskell-cabal-section-add-build-dependency](https://github.com/haskell/haskell-mode/blob/7100354a16a0502ed1730d1dfd1e3b9776969041/haskell-cabal.el). I wonder if the contributors of cabal made something similar.

Comment: Automatically? Based on what? Surely you don't want ALL your installed packages in your build-depends?

Comment: @Cubic Take, for instance, the [yesod-core .cabal file](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/yesod-core-1.4.9.1/src/). It's build-depends list 47 packages, some with version constraints. Did the author had to include them all by hand, writting them on the .cabal file himself, or did cabal help him with that?

Comment: They were probably added by hand. You can see the history of that file on GitHub: https://github.com/yesodweb/yesod/commits/master/yesod-core/yesod-core.cabal

Comment: @TaylorFausak Thanks, but how do you know that the changes were added by hand?

Comment: I don't. I'm guessing based on my experience with Cabal files in my own projects.

Comment: Also it's worth noting that [Cab](http://www.mew.org/~kazu/proj/cab/en/) (a wrapper around Cabal) does not have this feature. There is [an issue](https://github.com/kazu-yamamoto/cab/issues/12) for it, though.

Answer (score 4):

There are two tools in modern `cabal-install` for aiding with managing bounds of dependencies. First is `gen-bounds` which suggests proper version-ranges for packages based on the specifications of versions currently installed. The second is `outdated`, which lists dependencies in the `cabal` file for which newer versions exist on `hackage`. Both are documented in the cabal manual: https://www.haskell.org/cabal/users-guide/developing-packages.html#generating-dependency-version-bounds

Answer (score 0):

A possible alternative is to use hpack, yaml, sponge and jq:

You will need hpack package.yaml file.

For example to add `aeson` as a dependency:

```
cp package.yaml package.yaml.backup && (yaml2json package.yaml | jq '.dependencies += ["aeson"]' | json2yaml | sponge package.yaml ) && hpack
```